# Hide overflowing elements in a row and add a show more button

Tags: dart, flutter, material-design

[image]I would like to display a list of avatar chips in a row, if it is not enough room for all the avatars I would like to hide the overflowing ones and add a show more button instead. Do you know if a component like this exists for flutter?

See the picture above, if the items exceeds the space a (+5) button is shown, if this one is clicked I want to replace the list with a wrapped list that shows all the avatars.

Is it best to write a new layout component to accomplish this?

Comment: use `ListView()` or  `ListView.builder()` for example

Comment: @pskink do you have an example on how this can be done with a ListView? I have seen a lot of examples on creating a scrolling list view but not any where a show more button in inserted and the overflowing chips are hidden...

Comment: what do you need "more button" for? just use your finger to scroll yor list view left and right

Comment: show us some code about what you are working and we can help you